# Queue Implementation Using Linked Lists, Enqueue() not working

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public class Queue implements QueueInterface {

private class Node {
    Object data;
    Node next;

    Node(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
        // this.next = next;
    }
}

private Node head;
private Node tail;
private int  count;

// isEmpty()
// pre: none
// post: returns true if this Queue is empty, false otherwise
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
}

 // enqueue()
// adds newItem to back of this Queue
// pre: none
// post: !isEmpty()
public void enqueue(Object newItem) {

    Node p = new Node(newItem);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = tail = p;
    } else {
        tail.next = p;
        p = tail;
    }

}
// toString()
// overrides Object's toString() method
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (Node N = head; N != null; N = N.next) {
        s += N.data + " ";
    }
    return s;
}
 }
```

When I use a queue test java file. I try to enqueue the numbers 2, 5, 7 , and 10. however when I want to print out the elements, it only displays the first and last element.

I don't know if it's my toString function working incorrectly or is it the enqueue .-.

Answer (score 1):

The `enqueue` should update the `tail` to be the newly enqueued element:

```
public void enqueue(Object newItem) {

    Node p = new Node(newItem);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = tail = p;
    } else {
        tail.next = p;
        tail = p;  // instead of p = tail;
    }

}

public String toString() {
    // Use a StringBuilder instead of String
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Node N = head; N != null; N = N.next) {
        sb.append(N.data + " ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: p.s use StringBuilder and not String (in toString)

Comment: @manouti ty so much! but shouldn't the enqueues be printed in order? say for instance:
Enqueue(2)
Enqueue(3)
it should do 2 3, not 3 2

Comment: It's still wrong. It should be `tail.next = p; tail = p;` The OP had the `tail.next = p;` part correct.

Comment: @DavidConrad i got it to work to print out the enqueues, but it prints it out in reverse. trynna print it out in order .-.

Comment: @DavidConrad you are right. It was simply one line of code to change :) Post updated.